# How to use presentModalViewController in iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have created a Cartview and want to display this view as a modalview  when i click a button on productview.How can i do this ?
Actually i did this like

```
 UIViewController *nav=[[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"CartView-iPad"    bundle:nil];
    nav.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    nav.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
    CGRect frame=nav.view.frame;
    frame.origin.x -= 75;
    frame.origin.y = 100;
    nav.view.frame=CGRectMake(frame.origin.x,  frame.origin.y , 672, 393);
```

But the problem is the formsheet view is coming and my cart view is coming overt that i need only my cartview.Also i need a close button on the right to side of the cartview to dissmiss the modalview.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you're trying to set the frame of the modal view controller manually. This is, as far as I know, not recommended. The `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` option already indicates the desired size of the modal.

As for a back button, you should add a navigation bar with a back button in your `CartView-iPad`-xib-file. To make it work you have to make a subclass of UIViewController (example: `CartViewController`) which will handle the back button press. Right now `nav` is just a normal UIViewController which has no idea what to do with the actions in your xib-file.

Then in your new view controller, you can make a function like this that you connect your back button to:

```
- (IBAction)backButtonPressed
{
   [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```